# Перенаправление ссылки на изображение на страницу

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Возможно-ли с помощью `.htaccess` сделать так, чтобы изображение можно было показать на другом сайте, но при этом клик/переход по URL этого изображения вел на какую-нибудь страницу?

Например на [этой странице](http://bsas.controlcash.ru/t.html) есть два изображения. Клик по второму ведет на html-страницу с этим изображением. Как реализовать такое-же поведение для первого изображения?

Сейчас .htaccess выглядит так:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?test.controlcash.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ /$1.htm [NC,R=301,L]
```

То-есть перенаправление происходит, но само изображение не показывается.

Comment: Так допишите условие, какие изображения попадают под ваше правила, а не как тут `^([^/]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$` абсолютно все.

Comment: @Visman: не совсем вас понял. все изображения. Мне надо, что-бы я мог показывать картинку с хоста А на хосте Б/В/.../Я через `<img src="http://hostA/image123.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)">`, но при этом клик на эту картинку или переход на картинку через строку адреса браузера вел на `http://hostA/image123.htm`.  Второй изображение из моего примера - ведет себя именно так (fastpic.ru). Мне надо реализовать такое-же поведение.

Answer (score 1):

Возможное решение:

```
.htaccess:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ /$1.htm [NC,R=301,L]
```

Оно основанно на разнице в запросах - в заголовке Accept, который шлют браузеры при вызове встраиваемой картинки(`<img src="/image.png">`) и при клике или прямом переходе по URL картинки.

При встраивании заголовок ACCEPT содержит:
`image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8`

При клике / переходе:
`text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.`

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь невозможно определить, запрос к изображению идет для вставки в HTML или по клику на ссылку. Поэтому ваша задача нерешаема

Comment: Хм... парни из fastpic.ru как-то решили эту проблему

Comment: @Борис Клик по второму изображению отображает только картинку (без HTML). Не вижу, чтобы они вашу задачу как-то решили

Comment: ну... если честно - там как-то странно это срабатывает - через раз на третий. если клик привел на картинку, то обновление страницы уже покажет html.